# Beaglebone defaults to WiFi AP mode?

Tags: beagleboneblack

I've been struggling to get wifi working on my BBB for the better part of a week now. I sort of succeeded at one point, but I couldn't tell how I did it. Anyway, long story short, I noticed this morning that when I start a fresh debian image with my Edimax usb wifi installed, it defaults to AP mode and is broadcasting a SSID called "Beaglebone-710C". This makes sense with my problems because I could see the wifi dongle and see it was recognized, but I couldn't scan or connect. Does anyone know why it would default to AP mode? I think it might have something to do with me accessing the beaglebone via command line over USB? Thoughts? thanks!

Comment: Does this belong on SO at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following after logging in your BBB via SSH on the USB connection:
http://www.erdahl.io/2016/07/beaglebone-green-wifi-bluetooth-connect_18.html